# JsonSchema containing a data items which is 'untyped' json

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'd like to define a JSON schema which defines a hierarchy of data structures, but one of the data items is itself json but the schema for that data item is not strongly typed (ie unknown structure at the time of writing the schema). I would like the validator to be able to validate that this item is valid json, and I'd like to avoid having to use backslash-quote in the json in the way I would have to do if the data item were declared as a raw string.

Does JSON Schema support this?

More specifically (if it's relevant) I'm using C# and NewtonSoft JSONSchema classes.

Comment: ...or alternatively, define that the specific data item does conform to a schema, but the schema is 'named' in a field in the original json.

Comment: Quick test suggests declaring a property with type 'object' but no inner properties still validates it as json but allows any properties to be declared without error, which is I think what I want.... I think...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is to just declare something as 'object' - its parsed for json but not validated for members etc. I guess this is because 'allow an unknown property' is enabled by default for objects.